# bash: awk print with in print

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I need to grep some pattern and further i need to print some output within that. Currently I am using the below command which is working fine. But I like to eliminate using multiple pipe and want to use single awk command to achieve the same output. Is there a way to do it using awk?

```
root@Server1 # cat file
Jenny:Mon,Tue,Wed:Morning
David:Thu,Fri,Sat:Evening

root@Server1 # awk '/Jenny/ {print $0}' file | awk -F ":" '{ print $2 }' | awk -F "," '{ print $1 }'

Mon
```

I want to get this output using single awk command. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
awk -F: '/Jenny/ {split($2,a,","); print a[1]}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
awk -F'[:,]+' '/Jenny/{print $2}' file.txt
```

- It is using muliple `-F` value inside the `[ ]`
- The `+` means one or more since it is treated as a regex.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular job, I find `grep` to be slightly more robust.
Unless your company has a policy not to hire people named Eve.
(Try it out if you don't understand.)

```
grep -oP '^[^:]*Jenny[^:]*:\K[^,:]+' file
```

Or to do a whole-word match:

```
grep -oP '^[^:]*\bJenny\b[^:]*:\K[^,:]+' file
```

Or when you are confident that "Jenny" is the full name:

```
grep -oP '^Jenny:\K[^,:]+' file
```

Output:

```
Mon
```

Explanation:

- The stuff up until `\K` speaks for itself: it selects the line(s) with the desired name.
- `[^,:]+` captures the day of week (in this case `Mon`).
- `\K` cuts off everything preceding `Mon`.
- `-o` cuts off anything following `Mon`.